Can you help me calculate the balance of power (generated and dissipated) as well as calculate the curents?

I have the folowing problem in this task:
For the circuit in the picture, find the currents using Ohm's and Kirchhoff's laws, also calculate the balance of powers. The numerical values ​​are:
R1 = 40 Ω. R2 = 10 Ω, R3 = 20 Ω, R4 = 30 Ω, R5 = 25 Ω.
E2 = 10 V, E3 = 20 V.
The problem is that when I calculate the balance of power using the equations it is not equal. Can you explain why and how to calculate it properly?


I figured it out: the -(e2/R14) is wrong, it should be -(e2/R2) since they are in the same branch.
